# application architecture with JSF/IceFaces

Tags: jsf, dynamic, architecture, icefaces

Basically, I'm trying to implement an application having a Menu on the left (with a lot of items) and a 'container' filling the rest of the screen displaying the content selected through the menu.
I'm new to JSF but I'm used to other RIA technologies. So what I would do is having the content of the container being dynamically loaded every time the user clicks on an item of the menu (with Ajax, no complete page refresh). The content of the container could reload itself in certain cases as well.
Searching for an answer, the only comparable thing I found was an example having all the contents of the container already loaded (multiple panelGroups in a panelStack). When the user clicks on a menu, the selectedPanel property of the panelStack was changed. This doesn't fit the needs.
So what is the JSF/IceFaces way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Do you want something like the behaviour that is implemented in the ICEfaces Showcase example?

http://icefaces-showcase.icesoft.org/showcase.jsf

That example comes bundled with the ICEfaces distribution so that (or one of the examples in there) might provide some suggestions about how to go about it.